# How to zoom in and push image outside of the screen as I scroll down my page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am designing a website wherein I want to zoom in an image as I scroll down, and as that happens, the image will be pushed to left or right side of the screen as i scroll down the bottom (so like the image will be out of the screen as i scroll down). I've got the zoom in on scroll bit done, but I honestly don't know how to go with the moving to the left/right as I scroll. Any help will be appreciated. Thank you.

EDIT:

Here is what I have accomplished so far regarding on what I want to be able to do an the image.

HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
     <img src="http://www.freepngimg.com/download/plants/6-2-plants-free-download-png.png" class = "zoom">

    <script>
        $(window).on("scroll", function() {
            var s = Math.min(400, $(document).scrollTop()) + 200;
            $(".zoom").width(s).height(s);
        });
    </script>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
body{

width: 100%;
height: 1200px;
}

img {
    position: fixed;
    width: 200px;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

Comment: Please share the code you have with us it will be much easier to help :)

Comment: Edited it. Thanks :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly what you are trying to accomplish, maybe this could help?

```
$(window).on("scroll", function() {
  var scrollTop = $(document).scrollTop()
  var zoomAmount = Math.min(400, scrollTop) + 200

  $(".zoom").css({
    width: zoomAmount,
    height: zoomAmount,
    left: -scrollTop * 2,
  })
})
```

I've also formatted a little bit your code ;)

Let me know if this is what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Ah! This is exactly what I wanted to do! THANK YOU!

Comment: You are welcome :) I would also recommend taking a look at `debouncing` and `throttling` functions, as firing a callback on every scroll may be a little heavy if you have many event listeners.

Comment: Here are some resources to get you started. https://css-tricks.com/the-difference-between-throttling-and-debouncing/ and https://css-tricks.com/debouncing-throttling-explained-examples/

Comment: Thank you so much for the additional info!

Comment: I'm happy to help ;)

Answer (score 2):

I have made an example. Include this html

```
<div class="wrapper">
<img class="image" src="https://www.mozilla.org/media/img/firefox/home/switch-
to-firefox.fb1c114dfd84.png">
</div>
```

CSS

```
body{
height:2000px;
}
.wrapper{
}
.image{
 height:150px;
 width:150px;
 position:relative;
 left:0; 
 }
```

and javacsript

```
var oldScrollTop=0;
var newScrollTop;
$(window).scroll(function(e){

if($(window).scrollTop() <=150){ // you can manage the height of viewport of image here

newScrollTop = $(window).scrollTop()
var step = newScrollTop - oldScrollTop


var imageHeight = $('.image').css('height');
var imageWidth = $('.image').css('width');
 var imageLeft = $('.image').css('left');

var NewimageHeight = parseInt($('.image').css('height')) - step;
 var NewimageWidth = parseInt($('.image').css('width')) - step;
 var NewimageLeft =  parseInt($('.image').css('left')) -step;

$('.image').css({"height":NewimageHeight ,"width":NewimageWidth,  
"left":NewimageLeft});
oldScrollTop = newScrollTop;
}
})
```

this is link

https://jsfiddle.net/mustkeom/xy3dy4nL/32/

Answer (score 1):

CSS Transition will help you out with this:

```js
setTimeout(resizeAfterDelay, 1500)

function resizeAfterDelay() {
  $('div').addClass('move-left')
  
  setTimeout(moveAwayAfterDelay, 1500)
}

function moveAwayAfterDelay() {
  $('div').addClass('move-away')
}
```

```css
div {
  width: 100%;
  height: 250px;
  background: lightcoral;
  transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
  transition-property: width, height, transform;
  transform: translateX(0);
}

div.move-left {
  width: 20%;
  height: 100px;
}

div.move-away {
  transform: translateX(-150px);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div></div>
```

Comment: Thank you for this. Is there anyway for me to move the div out of the screen as it moves, though?

Comment: Thank you! This is very helpful.